# Node.js fs.readdir, fs.stat

Tags: node.js

I'm working through some tutorials and cannot understand why this line "self.only_dirs.push(files[i]);" is causing an error about it being 'undefined'.  This must be a variable scope problem but nothing I have tried has worked.  How to do I need to declare variables so that these embedded callback functions recognize them?

```js
function load_album_list(callback, callback2)
{
 var self = this;
 fs.readdir
 (
  'albums',
  function (err, files)
  {
   if(err)
   {
    callback(err, null);
    return;
   }
   
   var only_dirs = [];
   var remaining = files.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
   {

    fs.stat("albums/" + files[i],
      function(err, stats)
      {
       if(stats.isDirectory())
       {
        self.only_dirs.push(files[i]);
       }
       console.log("remaining: " + self.remaining);
       self.remaining -= 1;
       if (self.remaining == 0)
        callback(null, self.only_dirs); 
      }
     );

   }
   
   callback(null, only_dirs);
  }
 );
}
```

Comment: `self.only_dirs` is undefined when you call `push` on it.  the `var only_dirs = []` line does not create `self.only_dirs`.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function load_album_list(callback, callback2)
{
 var self = this;
    self.only_dirs = []; //<----- declare only_dirs in this scope
 fs.readdir
 (
  'albums',
  function (err, files)
  {
   if(err)
   {
    callback(err, null);
    return;
   }
   
   //var only_dirs = []; <--- remove this reference
   var remaining = files.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
   {

    fs.stat("albums/" + files[i],
      function(err, stats)
      {
       if(stats.isDirectory())
       {
        self.only_dirs.push(files[i]);
       }
       console.log("remaining: " + self.remaining);
       self.remaining -= 1;
       if (self.remaining == 0)
        callback(null, self.only_dirs); 
      }
     );

   }
   
   callback(null, self.only_dirs);
  }
 );
}
```